# traffic intercepting inline reverse proxy, Is this a service mesh pattern?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, servicemesh, aws-app-mesh

I have a cross-cutting authentication service that needs to be inserted in front of applications so that public internet traffic is routed through the auth service, which then reverse proxies it to the application, presumably via an internal domain/route.

Is this a service mesh pattern? If so, does it have a name?

I'm looking to implement something like this with AWS Appmesh in ECS. The upstream routing from ALB to IP filter seems straightforward, but the IP filter would then need to know that traffic to a public hostname should be routed to a specific internal domain, and I can't see how this could be implemented with AppMesh.